# Why the text editor shows some characters as unicode code points?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm crawling a website in python. The website text is in `iso-8859-1`. Once I read the HTML, I convert the text to utf-8 as so:

```
pageHTML = urllib.urlopen( url ).read()
pageHTML = pageHTML.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
```

I do some processing on the HTML, and store some tokens in an array. Then I dump the arrays as json into a file as so:

```
with open(outputPath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(tokens, f)
```

However, when I open the dumped file with a text editor I don't see real characters, but I see unicode code points as the following:

```
"hei\u00dfen"
```

which should be displayed as "heißen".

My questions:

1- why is that?

2- how to solve it?

The text editor is Atom. But also tried TextEdit on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

The default for `json.dump` is to assume ASCII output, meaning any non-ASCII Unicode character is represented using the `\uxxxx` notation. To change that set the `ensure_ascii` option to `False`. Some examples using `dumps`:

```
>>> print json.dumps("foö")
"fo\u00f6"
>>> print json.dumps("foö", ensure_ascii=False)
"foö"
```